# SQL Server 2017 on Linux in script upgrade mode after update

Tags: centos, sql-server

I have MS SQL Server 2017 running on CentOS for several months without a problem. Three days ago I applied `yum update` that included update for `mssql-server` as well. and ever since I can't connect to the server, getting the following error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Server is in script upgrade mode. Only administrator can connect at this time..

Most of the recommendations are to wait until script updates finish; but I waited for 3 days. Also restarted the service and restarted the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [Release Notes for SQL Server on Linux page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes). Microsoft's aware of the issue, and they write:

> Known upgrade issue - When you upgrade from a previous release to CU5,
>   SQL Server might fail to start with the following error:

```
Error: 4860, Severity: 16, State: 1.
Cannot bulk load. The file "C:\Install\SqlTraceCollect.dtsx" does not exist or you don't have file access rights.
Error: 912, Severity: 21, State: 2.
Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step 'msdb110_upgrade.sql' encountered error 200, state
```

> To resolve this error, enable SQL Server Agent and restart SQL Server with the following commands:

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set sqlagent.enabled true
sudo systemctl start mssql-server
```

Comment: is it really the same problem? the service itself didn't give me any errors! In any event, ran these commands and still unable to login

Comment: @Felix your best bet is to post the error log so we can see if it's the same issue.

Comment: I am sorry - I did what you said, and tried to connect immedaitely after that. But at that time sql was *indeed* running update scripts. it took some 20 minutes, but in the end it finished successfully, and I can connect! Error log was listing the scripts as it was running them. Sorry for doubting you :)

Comment: No no, you were right to doubt me! Always good to double check and keep asking questions. Glad it worked out!